# Remove vim status bar color?

Tags: vim

How can I remove the horrible color of my vim status bar has? I'd like it to be the same color as the background.

[image]

My current settings in my `~./.vimrc` file (or `~/.vimrc.after` file as I use) which relate to the status bar are:

```
set laststatus=2                            " Show the last status
hi statusline guibg=#263238

set statusline=%f                           " Filename

function! InsertStatuslineColor(mode)
  if a:mode == 'i'
    hi statusline guibg=#573E81 guifg=#263238
  elseif a:mode == 'r'
    hi statusline guibg=blue guifg=#263238
  else
    hi statusline guibg=red guifg=#263238
  endif
endfunction

au InsertEnter * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertChange * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertLeave * hi statusline guibg=#c5c8c6 guifg=#263238

" default the statusline to green when entering Vim
hi statusline guibg=#c5c8c6 guifg=#263238
```

Comment: Also if I guess you can have an answer here. Im sure you'll have more change on vim specific stack exchange site

Comment: @arainone no answers over there :(

Comment: @BarryBlade perhaps you should answer the comment there?

Comment: I don't have enough feedback to post a comment there

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to include this and remove everything else about `statusline` in your `.vimrc`

```
:hi StatusLine ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

Though I'm not sure it just depends on that, maybe also on your vim theme and on your terminal software.

Comment: I should have added I'm using MacVim. I tried the above anyway but it didn't work.

Comment: `:hi StatusLine guibg=NONE`  as you are using the gui version.

And to get Normal color: type `:hi Normal`